# Linq expression for a list inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary with a key and values as a list with my class StructureData.

```
private readonly Dictionary<IntBound, List<StructureData>> structuresDataCollection;
```

HouseStructureData is a child of StructureData.

If I want to check a first element of a certain type and return this element in a collection, I can use this:

```
public IEnumerable<StructureData> GetAllHousesData()
{
    return structuresDataCollection.Where(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault() is HouseStructureData).Select(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

How to write a linq expression to return all elements of a certain type from each list (Value)?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`OfType<>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype)

Comment: Why you return only the first data of each list list and not all, is that desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I want to check a first element of a certain type and return this element in a collection, I can use this

Or you can use `OfType`:

```
public IEnumerable<StructureData> GetAllHousesData() => 
    structuresDataCollection
        .Select(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault())
        .OfType<HouseStructureData>();
```

> How to write a linq expression to return all elements of a certain type from each list (Value)?

You can try using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) + [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-7.0):

```
public IEnumerable<StructureData> GetAllHousesData() => 
    structuresDataCollection
        .SelectMany(s => s.Value)
        .OfType<HouseStructureData>();
```

Comment: You can also simplify the existing code in a similar way:  
`public IEnumerable<StructureData> GetAllHousesData() { return structuresDataCollection.Select(s => s.Value.FirstOrDefault()).OfType<HouseStructureData>(); }`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think OP wanted to show what OP can/knows how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last question you only require a `SelectMany` with an `OfType`

> How to write a linq expression to return all elements of a certain type from each list (Value)?

```
private readonly Dictionary<IntBound, List<StructureData>> structuresDataCollection;

List<StructureData> houseStructureData = 
    // this bundle up all collections in collections 
    // like List<List<T>> in this case and convert it to List<T>
    structuresDataCollection.SelectMany(o =>
        // this is just returning the correct type. 
        // If none is found it return collection with 0 elements and works properly
        i.Values.OfType<HouseStructureData>()) 
        // return as a list or omit to get a IEnumerable
        .ToList();
```

You could write a cleaner generic version as a method

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetSpecificType<T>() where T : StructureData
{
    return structuresDataCollection.SelectMany(o => i.Values.OfType<T>());
}
```

Then use it like so

```
var houseData = GetSpecificType<HouseStructureData>().ToList();
```